# How to alter the mysql.user table

Tags: mysql

I am currently moving a MySQL server (5.5.25 on Windows 2008 R2) to a Windows Server 2022 with MySQL 5.7.40 (i have 0 experience with MySQL...). I would like to export the users on the 2008 server and import them in the new 2022 server.

When I do this, all is fine... But when I want to give the users permissions on the "new" database, I cannot do that because of the table count in the mysql.user database doesnt match.

There are 8 columns that are imported that are not the defaults when I install the Mysql server. When I drpop the columns, i can grant the permissions, make changes to passwords.... So a little captain obvious... I would like to add the columns to the mysql.user table without corruting it..

But, how can I add these columns to the table?

I used this to add them, but when I run this script, it becomes corrupted:

```
ALTER TABLE mysql.user
ADD COLUMN `FullName` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT '',
ADD COLUMN `User_Profile` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT '',
ADD COLUMN `LastAccess` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
ADD COLUMN `CreatedDate` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
ADD COLUMN `AccessCount` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
ADD COLUMN `ResetPassword` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
ADD COLUMN `EmployeeId` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
ADD COLUMN `ECD_version` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL
```

Error that I get when to change some user info:
`Error Code: 1805. Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 45, found 53. The table is probably corrupted`

*edit 1
Added screenshot of export mysql.user columns
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0jaC.png)

Hope someone would like to help me, many thanks!

Tim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must never, ever, directly modify in any way the [catalog tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_catalog) of any database.

Do **not** alter `mysql.user`.

Instead, export the old database user data and use a script/app code to convert the exported data to `create user` statements suitable for the target database and save them to a file, then execute the file against the target.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, good to know! Noted, wont do it again. Any recommendations for the app/code convert them to a file?

The export is a mysqldump of the mysql.user table, is that correct?

Comment: Use whatever you're comfortable with. Bash script, python, java, whatever. Since it's a one-time activity, you could even just use your favourite text editor to manually convert the syntax.

Comment: Alright, will take a look at that. But if i use the mysql.user dump, it does contain the columns listed in the firts post. I need those columns to start up some legacy software that uses the mysql database. I added a screenshot of the export mysql.user columns

Comment: I would check with the supplier of that legacy applucation. You may have to use a specific mysql version or a certain setting to allow you such changes. The mysql database tables nowadays use innodb, not myisam, so this must be a quite old app.

Comment: An easy way to produce the `create user` and `grant` statements is to use the free Percona script [pt-show-grants](https://docs.percona.com/percona-toolkit/pt-show-grants.html)